# header.php not including in custom page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Please make me correct where is the problem and what should i do,

i am trying to make my custom page template in wordpress. Also the default landing page,
What i did is, just created a file `jp_home.php` and set the `Template Name: name here`.

And then create a page with the name home and select the theme for the home page, second i went on the `settings>reading>` and select the a static page and select my home page as a landing page.

All these changes i have done in `themes/twentyeleven/` template.

**NOW the problem:** in `jp_home.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: WebTech Eleven
 */

//get_header('new');
?>

<!-- Wrapper Start -->
<div id="wrapper">
    Here is my Page
</div>
<!-- End Wrapper -->
<?php
    get_footer();   
//require("footer_old.php");
?>
```

after commenting the `get_header()` i am still viewing my `header.php` i don't know why?? and the rest part not visible.  Can anyone please explain what wrong i have done??
    ?>

Comment: Is that the entire file or is there an opening php tag above and a closing one below? You need to start with `<?php` before any php code in the file and at the end of all php code, you need to close with `?>`

Comment: thanks for you reply i gave `<?php` tags but don't know why not showing here, but sure this is not the problem..

Comment: can anyone tell me why giving me negative on this question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you still see the content from the header and none of the changes/additions in your `jp_home.php` then WordPress isn't pulling up that template file.

It sounds like you're doing everything you need to but lets just review how to accomplish what you're looking for.

Ensure that you have `jp_home.php` in the `twentyeleven` theme directory. With that in place, go ahead and create your `Home` page. Select `WebTech Eleven` under the Template option and save the page. After that, go to your Settings > Reading and make sure that your Front Page is set to display a static page, and set that to `Home`.

Make sure you are then actually navigating to the correct home page and you'll see the new template in action (a good way to do this is to navigate to edit your Home page and click "View Page"). I just tested all of this locally and it works for me.

Very clear and concise tutorial here also: http://wsmithdesign.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/creating-a-custom-wordpress-home-page-template/

Comment: thanks i did the same, means review all and then it works, didn't understand where were the problem, well thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

Go to Pages -> All Pages and open the page you want to use the template on (THAT static page in your case). On the edit page, did you choose "WebTech Eleven" under templates?

[image]

Also, I must ask. Have you tried clearing cache on client side, and server side if you're using any cache there?